# Dynamically check for SELECT duplicate value

Tags: jquery

the goal I'm aiming for is to check all the SELECT element for duplicated values (can't select the same value in 2 SELECTs)
I've done lots of searching but all of it 2 SELECTs not fixable for more

the logic I tried:

> check function(){
>      declare values array, errorElement array
>      foreach(select element){ 
>      if the selected value exist in the value array(duplicate), add the element to the error element array
>      else add the value to the value array
>      }
>      if no error elements (no duplicated values), remove the error class from all selects
>      else foreach(select elemnt){
>      if the select exists in the error element array, set error class
>      else remove error class
>      }
>   }
>
> on any select change, call  check function

and here the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6YAns/)

```
function checkSelects() 
{ 
    var errorElements = []; var values = [];

    $("select").each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), values) !== -1) {
            errorElements.push($(this).attr('id'));
        } else {
            values.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    if (errorElements.length === 0) {
        $("select").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
        });
    } else {
        $("select").each(function () {
            if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), errorElements) !== -1) {
                $(this).addClass('error');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('error');
            }
        });
    }
}

$(function () {
     $("select").change(function () {
        checkSelects();
     }); 
});
```

as for functionality it works perfect, setting the error class for one side of the duplicate conflict. but I'd like to make it even more clear and set the error class for both sides

is that going over-board? any pointer how to achieve that?
here's a screen-cap of it
[image]

selecting text1 in 2 SELECTs only sets the error class for the later element.
I'd like for both text1s to be shown in red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply filter all select boxes with the same value and mark all of them at once.

I've also simplified the code a fair bit by clearing all errors when the check starts.

```
function checkSelects() 
{
    var $elements = $('select');

    $elements
        .removeClass('error')
        .each(function () {
            var selectedValue = this.value;

            $elements
                .not(this)
                .filter(function() {
                    return this.value == selectedValue;
                })
                .addClass('error');
        });
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6YAns/4/)

Comment: Thank you so much for answer, it's useful

Answer (score 4):

Use like this

```
function checkSelects() {
    var errorElements = [];
    var values = [];

    $("select").each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), values) !== -1) {
            errorElements.push($(this).attr('id'));
        } else {
            values.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    if (errorElements.length === 0) {
        $("select").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
        });
    } else {
        $("select").each(function () {
            if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), errorElements) !== -1) {
                $(this).addClass('error');
                $("select[value="+$(this).val()+"]").addClass('error'); <---- here
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('error');
            }
        });
    }

}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6YAns/1/)

**Eidt**

I've simplified your code,  you can use like this way too

```
function checkSelects() {
    $(".error").removeClass("error");
    $("select").each(function () {
        if ($("select[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").length > 1) {
            $("select[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").addClass('error');
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        checkSelects();
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6YAns/2/)**

Comment: I've tried this in my code but it didn't work. I alerted `$(this).attr('value')` and it's undefined while `$(this).val()` gets the value correctly.. I might've dropped the mention of Zend which I use to get the form in the first place but I thought that wouldn't matter with jquery since the same html tags get delivered. +1ed anyway since it work even if not for me:^) thank you

Comment: @katia did you check the fiddle?

Comment: yes, I did. I've tried it separately and it works, I guess there's something else in my project getting in the way of the script to work